# How to get parent Id from a run time generated row_number() as unique id in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have removed while loop used before but furnishing exact results. Now everything works fine except parentkey.
How to get "parentkey" in the stored procedure perfectly??
The procedure furnishes wrong results if more than 1 same parent is addded in same/different level of bom. The results shows one parent for all childs. It should show both parents separately with childs. The following part does not furnish exact result in case explained above.

```
(SELECT MAX(e.idcolumn) FROM #tExplode E WHERE e.fcomponent = b.fparent AND e.fcomprev = b.fparentrev AND e.cfacilityid = b.pfacilityid AND e.idcolumn > 0 ) As parentkey

IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'M2M_Std_BOM_Explosion' AND type = 'P')
       DROP PROCEDURE M2M_Std_BOM_Explosion
    GO


CREATE Procedure [dbo].[M2M_Std_BOM_Explosion] 
@pcPartNo CHAR(25), 
@pcPartRev CHAR(3), 
@pcFac CHAR(20), 
@plIndent Bit

As
Begin
    set nocount on

if object_id('tempdb..#tExplode') is not null drop table #tExplode

declare @sql as varchar(max) = ''

create table #tExplode
    (
        ID int not null,
        lvl int not null,
        CompPath varchar(8000),
        ItmPath varchar(8000),
        display varchar(100),
        fcomponent varchar(25),
        cfacilityid varchar(20),
        fcomprev varchar(3),
        fparent varchar(25),
        fparentrev varchar(3),
        pfacilityid varchar(20),
        fitem varchar(6),
        fqty numeric(15,5), 
        fsumqty numeric(15,5), 
        fst_ef_dt datetime, 
        fend_ef_dt datetime, 
        bomid int,
        fnoperno int,
        fltooling bit,
        fbommemo varchar(8000),
        fprodcl varchar(20),
        flfssvc bit,
        idcolumn Integer,
        timestamp_column timestamp,
        flextend bit, 
        fcompudrev varchar(3),
        fcparudrev varchar(3),
        forder int
    )

    Insert into  #tExplode( ID,lvl,CompPath,ItmPath,display,fcomponent,cfacilityid,fcomprev,
                            fparent,fparentrev,pfacilityid,fitem,fqty,fsumqty,fst_ef_dt, 
                            fend_ef_dt,bomid,fnoperno,fltooling,fbommemo,flfssvc,flextend,
                            fcompudrev,fcparudrev,forder,idcolumn)
                            SELECT 1,
                                   0,
                                   Cast(Rtrim(ltrim(@pcFac))+rtrim(ltrim(@pcPartNo))+rtrim(ltrim(@pcPartRev)) as varchar(8000)),
                                   Cast(rtrim(ltrim(@pcFac))+rtrim(ltrim(@pcPartNo))+rtrim(ltrim(@pcPartRev)) as Varchar(8000)),
                                   cast(1 AS varchar(100)),
                                   @pcPartNo,
                                   @pcFac,
                                   @pcPartRev,
                                   '',
                                   '',
                                   '',
                                   '',
                                   1,
                                   1, 
                                   {d '1900-01-01'}, 
                                   {d '1900-01-01'}, 
                                   0,
                                   '',
                                   0,
                                   '',
                                   0,
                                   0,
                                   '',
                                   '',
                                    0,
                                    0
                            FROM (SELECT @pcFac fac,
                                                @pcPartNo fpartno,
                                                         @pcPartRev frev) x
                            LEFT JOIN inrtgc i On i.fac=x.fac And i.fpartno=x.fpartno And i.fcpartrev=x.frev

                           ; WITH t AS (
                           select ID,lvl,CompPath,ItmPath,display,fcomponent,cfacilityid,fcomprev,
                                  fparent,fparentrev,pfacilityid,fitem,fqty,fsumqty,fst_ef_dt, 
                                     fend_ef_dt,
                                     bomid,
                                     fnoperno,
                                     fltooling,
                                     fbommemo,
                                     flfssvc,
                                     flextend,
                                     fcompudrev,
                                     fcparudrev,
                                     forder
                                     from #tExplode

                            UNION ALL

                             SELECT    b.identity_column,
                                       t.lvl+1, 
                                 rtrim(ltrim(t.CompPath)) + '!' + rtrim(ltrim(b.pfacilityid)) + rtrim(ltrim(b.fcomponent)) + Replicate(' ',25-Len(rtrim(ltrim(b.fcomponent))))+ rtrim(ltrim(b.fcomprev + '!')),
                                 rtrim(ltrim(t.ItmPath)) + '!' + rtrim(ltrim(b.fitem)),
                                 Cast(replicate(' ',2*t.lvl) + b.fcomponent as Varchar(100)),
                                 Cast(b.fcomponent as Varchar(25)),
                                 Cast(b.cfacilityid as Varchar(20)),
                                 Cast(b.fcomprev as Varchar(3)),
                                 Cast(b.fparent as Varchar(25)),
                                 Cast(b.fparentrev as Varchar(3)),
                                 Cast(b.pfacilityid as Varchar(20)),
                                 Cast(b.fitem as varchar(6)),
                                 b.fqty,
                                 Cast(CASE
                                     WHEN b.flextend = 1 THEN b.fqty * ISNULL(t.fsumqty, cast(1 AS numeric(15,5)))
                                     ELSE b.fqty
                                 END as Numeric(15,5)),
                                 b.fst_ef_dt,
                                 b.fend_ef_dt,
                                 b.identity_column,
                                 ISNULL(b.fnoperno,cast(0 AS int)),
                                 b.fltooling,
                                 Cast(b.fbommemo as Varchar(8000)),
                                 b.flfssvc,
                                 b.flextend,
                                 Cast(b.fcompudrev as Varchar(3)),
                                 Cast(b.fcparudrev as Varchar(3)),
                                 0
                                FROM inboms b
                                inner join t ON b.pFacilityID = t.cFacilityID
                                AND b.fparent = t.fcomponent
                                AND b.fparentrev = t.fcomprev
                                )


                    insert into #tExplode 
                    (ID,lvl,CompPath,ItmPath,display,fcomponent,cfacilityid,fcomprev,
                     fparent,fparentrev,pfacilityid,fitem,fqty,fsumqty,fst_ef_dt, 
                             fend_ef_dt,
                             bomid,
                             fnoperno,
                             fltooling,fbommemo,flfssvc,
                             flextend,
                             fcompudrev,fcparudrev,forder,idcolumn)
                    select  ID,lvl,CompPath,ItmPath,display,fcomponent,cfacilityid,fcomprev,
                            fparent,fparentrev,pfacilityid,fitem,fqty,fsumqty,fst_ef_dt, 
                             fend_ef_dt,
                             bomid,
                             fnoperno,
                             fltooling,fbommemo,
                             flfssvc,
                             flextend,
                             fcompudrev,fcparudrev,forder,row_number() over (order by lvl,comppath,cfacilityid,fcomponent,fcomprev,forder) from t


                    Set @sql = 'select b.idcolumn,b.lvl, 
                            b.comppath,
                            b.itmpath,
                            b.display, 
                            CASE WHEN m.fluseudrev = 1 THEN b.fcompudrev ELSE b.fcomprev END as disprev, 
                            b.fitem, 
                            fsource, 
                            b.fqty, 
                            CASE when b.flextend = 1 then b.fsumqty ELSE ((b.fqty * ISNULL(b.fsumqty, cast(1 AS numeric(15,5))))/Isnull(i.fSpq,1)) END as fsumqty, 
                            fmeasure,
                            b.fnoperno, 
                            CASE WHEN inbomm.fpartno IS NULL THEN SPACE(1)        ELSE ''*'' END as isparent, --Working
                            b.fst_ef_dt, 
                            b.fend_ef_dt, 
                            b.bomid,
                            b.fcomponent,
                            b.cfacilityid,
                            b.fcomprev,
                            m.fdescript as fdesc, 
                            b.fparent,
                            b.fparentrev,
                            b.pfacilityid,
                            ISNULL(m.identity_column, CAST(0 As Int)) as partid, 
                            fidims, 
                            Case When m.fcstscode=''O'' Then ''Obsolete''
                                    Else
                                        CASE WHEN NOT ((b.fst_ef_dt IS NULL) OR (b.fst_ef_dt={d ''1900-01-01''})) AND 
                                                DATEDIFF(day,b.fst_ef_dt, GetDate()) < 0 
                                                THEN ''Future'' 
                                            WHEN NOT ((b.fend_ef_dt IS NULL) OR (b.fend_ef_dt={d ''1900-01-01''})) AND 
                                                DATEDIFF(day,b.fEnd_ef_dt, GETDATE()) > 0 
                                            THEN ''Expired''
                                            ELSE ''Current''
                                        END
                                    End as effectivity, 
                            b.fltooling,
                            b.fbommemo,
                            m.fprodcl,
                            fllotreqd,
                            b.flfssvc,
                            b.timestamp_column,
                            (SELECT MAX(e.idcolumn) FROM #tExplode E WHERE             e.fcomponent = b.fparent AND e.fcomprev = b.fparentrev AND e.cfacilityid = b.pfacilityid AND e.idcolumn > 0 ) As parentkey,
                            b.flextend,
                            m.fluseudrev,  
                            b.fcompudrev,
                            b.fcparudrev,
                            b.forder  
                        from #tExplode b LEFT OUTER JOIN inmastx m ON
                                        b.cFacilityID = m.fac AND
                                        b.fcomponent = m.fpartno AND
                                        b.fcomprev = m.frev

                            LEFT OUTER JOIN inbomm ON
                                        b.pfacilityid = inbomm.facilityid AND
                                        b.fComponent = InBomm.fPartno AND
                                        b.fCompRev   = InBomm.fcPartRev
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN inrtgc i ON
                                        b.pfacilityid = i.fac AND
                                        b.fComponent = i.fPartno AND
                                        b.fCompRev   = i.fcPartRev
                        where ' + case when @plIndent= 1 then  'b.lvl >= 1' else 'b.lvl = 1' end + '
                        order by ' + case when @plIndent= 1 then  'b.comppath,b.cfacilityid,b.fcomponent,b.fcomprev,b.forder'  else 'b.comppath,b.forder' end + ''

                        Exec(@sql)

                        drop table #tExplode

end
--How to get "parentkey" in the stored procedure perfectly??
--The procedure furnishes wrong results if more than 1 same parent is addded in --same/different level of bom. The results shows one parent for all childs.
```

Comment: Can you please simplify your question until it only contains the problem you are facing?

Comment: I have generated Unique Id for each record using row_number() in CTE.

Comment: I have generated Unique Id for each record using row_number() in CTE. From those Unique Ids I want parent id which are having childs. Its working for normal parent childs but it fails when same parent is added in different levels or same level. Max(idcolumn) in the query results in same parent for all childs.